# "Could not find concurrent-ruby-1.1.7 in any of the sources" when deploy rails with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

I saw a lot of similar questions here, but nothing of provided advises has helped. Every time I run `cap production deploy` I got error:

```
...
 DEBUG [9b1f0199] Running RBENV_ROOT=$HOME/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.6.5 $HOME/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec bundle check as deploy@199.192.25.241
 DEBUG [9b1f0199] Command: cd /home/deploy/project/releases/20201018151933 && ( export RAILS_ENV="production" RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.6.5" ; RBENV_ROOT=$HOME/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.6.5 $HOME/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec bundle check )
 DEBUG [9b1f0199]       Could not find concurrent-ruby-1.1.7 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
 DEBUG [9b1f0199] Finished in 1.400 seconds with exit status 7 (failed).
  INFO [f0be72cf] Running RBENV_ROOT=$HOME/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.6.5 $HOME/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec bundle install --jobs 1 --without development test --deployment --quiet as deploy@199.192.25.241
 DEBUG [f0be72cf] Command: cd /home/deploy/project/releases/20201018151933 && ( export RAILS_ENV="production" RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.6.5" ; RBENV_ROOT=$HOME/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.6.5 $HOME/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec bundle install --jobs 1 --without development test --deployment --quiet )
 DEBUG [f0be72cf]       Could not find concurrent-ruby-1.1.7 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
#<Thread:0x00007feee097d1d8@/Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
        13: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
        12: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `run'
        11: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `instance_exec'
        10: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/capistrano-bundler-1.6.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/bundler.cap:26:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
         9: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:92:in `within'
         8: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/capistrano-bundler-1.6.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/bundler.cap:27:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
         7: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:100:in `with'
         6: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/capistrano-bundler-1.6.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/bundler.cap:39:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
         5: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:80:in `execute'
         4: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `create_command_and_execute'
         3: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `tap'
         2: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
         1: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:170:in `execute_command'
/Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/command.rb:97:in `exit_status=': bundle exit status: 7 (SSHKit::Command::Failed)
bundle stdout: Could not find concurrent-ruby-1.1.7 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
bundle stderr: Nothing written
        1: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as deploy@199.192.25.241: bundle exit status: 7 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
bundle stdout: Could not find concurrent-ruby-1.1.7 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
bundle stderr: Nothing written
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@199.192.25.241: bundle exit status: 7
bundle stdout: Could not find concurrent-ruby-1.1.7 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
bundle stderr: Nothing written


Caused by:
SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 7
bundle stdout: Could not find concurrent-ruby-1.1.7 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
bundle stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:updated => bundler:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deploy@199.192.25.241: bundle exit status: 7
bundle stdout: Could not find concurrent-ruby-1.1.7 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
bundle stderr: Nothing written
```

My **Capfile**:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# Load DSL and set up stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Include default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'

# Load the SCM plugin appropriate to your project:
#
# require "capistrano/scm/hg"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Hg
# or
# require "capistrano/scm/svn"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Svn
# or
require 'capistrano/scm/git'
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#   https://github.com/capistrano/passenger
#
# require "capistrano/rvm"
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
require 'capistrano/rails'
# require "capistrano/chruby"
require 'capistrano/bundler'
# require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
# require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/passenger'

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }

set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.6.5'
```

My **Gemfile**:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'

gem 'aasm'
gem 'aws-sdk-s3', require: false
gem 'bcrypt', require: 'bcrypt'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false
gem 'devise'
gem 'draper'
gem 'factory_bot_rails'
gem 'ffaker'
gem 'gon'
gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-line'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
gem 'pundit'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3'
gem 'ransack', github: 'activerecord-hackery/ransack'
gem 'rollbar'
gem 'ruby-vips', '~> 2.0.17'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'serviceworker-rails'
gem 'slim-rails'
gem 'strong_migrations'
gem 'travis'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
end

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.6'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.6'
  gem 'capistrano-passenger', '~> 0.2.0'
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.4'
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.4'
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.2'
  gem 'rubocop'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'database_cleaner-active_record'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'simplecov', require: false
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby]
```

First message was about rollbar gem (and deploy was after I've added this gem to project), but when I run bundle update, I got this error about `concurrent-ruby-1.1.7`. I've tried already:

1. Remove Gemfile.lock
2. Run bundle upadte and bundle install
3. Add this code to **Capfile**:

```
      set :default_environment, {
        :PATH => '$HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin:$PATH',
        :GEM_HOME => '$HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5',
        :GEM_PATH => '$HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5:$HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5@global'
      }
```

4. Run `bundle exec cap production deploy:updated`

`cap production deploy:check` doesn't show any error. What am I missing? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: I guess that when you run bundle install yourself, it runs ok? Can you cd into the release folder and run it from there?

Comment: yes from the realease folder `bundle install` works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solved it:

1. Go to server command line
2. As we can see in error log, the last command before error appears was:

`Command: cd /home/deploy/project/releases/20201018151933 && ( export RAILS_ENV="production" RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.6.5" ; RBENV_ROOT=$HOME/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.6.5 $HOME/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec bundle check )`

So we go to our folder:

`cd /home/deploy/project/releases/20201018151933`

and run there command:

`export RAILS_ENV="production" RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.6.5" ; RBENV_ROOT=$HOME/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.6.5 $HOME/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec bundle check`

After that we see same error:

`Could not find concurrent-ruby-1.1.7 in any of the sources. Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems.`

3. In same folder run `bundle install` and after gem installed we can exit out of server command line.
4. Run `cap production deploy` and everything is gonna be fine.

I still don't know what is the root problem of this error, and how to fix it permanently, but this works for me. I hope it will be useful for anyone else.